# Updating StockItem with WarehouseDetails

Tags: acumatica

Has anyone successfully updated a stockitem with the WarehouseDetails array included? I keep getting a stack dump in every variation I have tried. We are using the Manufacturing module, and I'm not sure if that makes a difference on the behaviour.

PUT http://myserver-name-here/entity/Default/20.200.001/StockItem/$expand=WarehouseDetails

```
{
    "id": "0aeba316-893b-eb11-817c-06ec5f1e3982",
    "InventoryID": {"value": "MYSKU.VALUE"},            
    "WarehouseDetails": [
        {
            "id": "0ceba316-893b-eb11-817c-06ec5f1e3982",
            "rowNumber": {"value": 1},
            "DefaultIssueLocationID": {"value": "WH1"},
            "DefaultReceiptLocationID": {"value": "WH2"} ,
            "WarehouseID": {"value": "LOCATION1"},
            "custom": {},
            "files": [],
            "note": {"value": ""}
        },
        {
            "id": "d070a3df-d343-eb11-817c-06ec5f1e3982",   
            "rowNumber": {"value": 2},
            "DefaultIssueLocationID": {"value": "WH3"},
            "DefaultReceiptLocationID": {"value": "WH4"}    ,
            "WarehouseID": {"value": "LOCATION2"}    ,
            "custom": {},
            "files": [],
            "note": {"value": ""}    
        }
    ]
}
```

The stack dump is always this

```
{
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.\r\nParameter name: Invalid uri structure",
    "exceptionType": "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException",
    "stackTrace": "   at System.Monads.ArgumentCheck.Check[TSource](TSource source, Func`2 checkCondition, Func`2 exceptionSource)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.SystemContracts.V2.RestController.PutFile(String objectName, String ids)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_2.<GetExecutor>b__2(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()"
}
```

Comment: as per error message. your URI is wrong. you don't need to specify the "expand". its only for GET.

Comment: Not entirely true Rick, the $expand returns the section on success.

Comment: you don't need it. i just tried "http://<baseurl>/entity/Default/20.200.001/StockItem". it returned the warehouse details nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a backslash after StockItem, remember it's a question mark to enter any parameters.  That is why you are getting an invalid uri error.

https://{{baseUrl}}/entity/Default/20.200.001/StockItem?$expand=WarehouseDetails

Comment: Well that is embarrassing Kulvir. Sometimes its the silly things right in front of your face. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately I hit a new problem with this API call. The call succeeds with 200 response, but the "DefaultIssueLocationID" and "DefaultReceiptLocationID" values are never updated.

Comment: Seems that part of the API does not work but a PUT to ItemWarehouse does!